# Tests stop running on TeamCity after updating test station to Windows 7

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, teamcity, nunit-2.5.9

We just switched our test station from Windows XP to Windows 7 and unexpected problem appeared.

We run tests using NUnit 2.5.9 and at some point during running on Windows XP we were getting warnings from TeamCity:

```
[16:05:27][Step 2/16] 2013-09-20 16:05:28,181 [watchDog] WARN JetBrains.Container.Log4netDefaultLoggerInitializer - Unhandled exception in current domain: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain., , (null)
[16:05:27][Step 2/16] 2013-09-20 16:05:28,181 [1232] WARN JetBrains.Container.Log4netDefaultLoggerInitializer - Unhandled exception in current domain: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain., , (null)
[16:05:27][Step 2/16] 2013-09-20 16:05:28,181 [2684] WARN JetBrains.Container.Log4netDefaultLoggerInitializer - Unhandled exception in current domain: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain., , (null)
[16:05:27][Step 2/16] 2013-09-20 16:05:28,181 [5940] WARN JetBrains.Container.Log4netDefaultLoggerInitializer - Unhandled exception in current domain: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain., , (null)
[16:05:27][Step 2/16] 2013-09-20 16:05:28,181 [2724] WARN JetBrains.Container.Log4netDefaultLoggerInitializer - Unhandled exception in current domain: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain., , (null)
```

and the following error message window popped up:

[image]

but tests were still running and finishing successfully.

Right now with switching to Windows 7, we are getting those warnings as errors:

```
[10:48:31][Step 2/16] 2013-09-30 10:48:30,862 [watchDog] WARN JetBrains.Container.Log4netDefaultLoggerInitializer - Unhandled exception in current domain: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain., , (null)
[10:48:31][Step 2/16]
[10:48:31][Step 2/16] 2013-09-30 10:48:30,862 [564] WARN JetBrains.Container.Log4netDefaultLoggerInitializer - Unhandled exception in current domain: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain., , (null)
[10:48:31][Step 2/16] Unhandled Exception: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.
[10:48:31][Step 2/16] 2013-09-30 10:48:30,862 [5088] WARN JetBrains.Container.Log4netDefaultLoggerInitializer - Unhandled exception in current domain: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain., , (null)
[10:48:31][Step 2/16]
[10:48:31][Step 2/16] 2013-09-30 10:48:30,865 [5840] WARN JetBrains.Container.Log4netDefaultLoggerInitializer - Unhandled exception in current domain: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain., , (null)
[10:48:31][Step 2/16] Unhandled Exception: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.
[10:48:31][Step 2/16] 2013-09-30 10:48:30,866 [4004] WARN JetBrains.Container.Log4netDefaultLoggerInitializer - Unhandled exception in current domain: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain., , (null).
```

The same Error message appears and tests are **stop** running.
The short workaround I found so far is just to close this error window and test are continue to run.
I am wondering if there is a way to catch this exception somehow in TeamCity test configuration, or any other proper workaround?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of tests are your running? Also, do you really close warning dialogs in your build server? Normally you have it running and communicate with it through the web interface, the REST API etc. Do you have people log on to the machine from timeto time and close warnings?

Comment: I am running Unit tests, it's about 200 of them, and yes, as I mentioned for now I found the solution just to log to the station and close window manually.

Comment: You need to present a lot more details on the tests and the setup. You are looking for a solution to the problem you had on both OS's.

Comment: This appears to have been cross-posted to the JetBrains forum [here](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5500072). An issue was added to their tracking system, YouTrack, [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-32547) and has no assignee or resolution.

Comment: I've experienced the same exception though with a slightly different consequences - had a NUnit runner configured trying to run all the tests from all the projects determined by wildcards - e.g. *UnitTests/bin/debug/*UnitTests.dll. By some mistake there was a unit test project - SampleUniTests.dll containing a reference to a Sample2UnitTests.dll and once the wildcards resolved the path like "SampleUnitTests/bin/debug/Sample2UnitTests.dll" this kind of exception occurred which is understandable but quite hard to spot sometimes.